# Kubernetes load balancing between cluster nodes

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes cluster with 6 worker nodes.

Could anyone explain how Kubernetes works balancing the load between nodes? Any algorithm?

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Please, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

The Kubernetes Scheduler decides how to balance your pods between nodes
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/kube-scheduler/

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the default Kubernetes scheduler and it’s operation to select a node for a pod.

[Node selection in kube-scheduler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/kube-scheduler/)

You can also influence the scheduling by utilising node labels, node-selector, pod affinity/anti-affinity.

[Assigning Pods to Nodes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/)